# Can not clone project from gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

I've lauched a private project named 'project_name' on GitLab.

But when I try to use "`git clone git@gitlab.xyz:user_name/project_name.git`" on another server, GitLab informed me to input "`git@gitlab.xyz's password`".
After inputing three unknow password, It said "`Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive)`"!

How Can I Config My Server To Access 'project_name' Successfully?

Comment: Did you register your SSH key with GitLab? Are you running an SSH authentication agent (only if you're on Windows)?

Comment: I've register my SSH key on server A, and can see it on gitlab's web page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've register my SSH key on server `A`

You need to create a register another pair of public/private ssh keys on server `B`, in order for your git clone command to succeed there.

(This is much better than copy your public/private keys from `~/.ssh` of server A to server B: you are not supposed to reuse a private ssh key).

Comment: Thanks a looooooot! I registered another ssh key on server B and added it in my GitLab. Then I can clone repo on server B.